# What should I do if I bought prime rib roast too early?

Tags: food-safety, beef

I have just purchased my Christmas prime rib from Costco (boneless). We are 13 days away from Christmas, so I think I bought it too early. Should I freeze it or dry age it on a rack in the coldest part of the fridge with salt and pepper crust?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical refrigerator temperature is a bit too cold for true dry aging. I don't think you will perceive much of a difference, even under ideal conditions, in only two weeks.  So, for me, the decision is based on whether or not I want a prime rib taking up prime real estate in my refrigerator.  I would freeze until a couple of days before your meal.

Answer (score 0):

If your budget allow, why not dry run Christmas roast on this  rib and order new one for later. This way you get to perfect your skill and your family get double Christmas.